# Binomial Theorem - Proving

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

The viscosity $\eta$ of a liquid is given by;

$$\eta = \frac{kr^4}{v*l}$$

Where $k$ is a constant.

If there is an error in $r$ of $+2%$, in $v$ of $+4%$ and $l$ of $-3%$, what is the resultant error in $\eta$?

Comment: Hello, Andre. It's considered bad form to just post a homework question and expect someone else to do all the work for you. Please see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) post about how to ask for help with homework. Also, very good advice on how to ask a good question in general can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Comment: I don't see the meaning of $binomial$ $theorem$ in the title of your post.

Comment: Hello. Sorry I ought to explain myself after reading the post 'homework' as I am new to the website. I have been working my way through the book 'Higher Engineering Mathematics' by John Bird, which I found extremely useful. However after following the binomial series chapter I attempted to complete the exercises for practical problems involving the binomial theorem. I have struggled completing the question posted here. Therefore guidance on such question would be much appreciated! For assistance do I post within the homework section? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start again with your model as a good illustration. You have $$\eta = \frac{kr^4}{v*l}$$

where $k$ is a constant.

Now, you want to consider the impact of a small change for any parameter. So, you consider the total derivative with respect to all parameters. This then leads in your case to $$d\eta=-\frac{k r^4 dl}{l^2 v}-\frac{k r^4 dv}{l v^2}+\frac{4 k r^3 dr}{l v}$$

Now you change the $d$'s by $\Delta$'s which are not more infinitesimal and so  $$\Delta \eta =-\frac{\text{$\Delta $l} k r^4}{l^2 v}-\frac{\text{$\Delta $v} k r^4}{l
   v^2}+\frac{4 \text{$\Delta $r} k r^3}{l v}$$ So, for any $\Delta l$,  $\Delta v$ or  $\Delta r$, you have the analytical expression of $\Delta \eta$.

In the case where your function is a product, it is much easier to go to logarithms before differentiating. So, for your problem, we shall have  $$\frac{\Delta \eta }{\eta }=-\frac{\text{$\Delta $l}}{l}+\frac{4 \text{$\Delta $r}}{r}-\frac{\text{$\Delta
   $v}}{v}$$

In the case of the product, you immediately see that a $1$% increase of $r$ will induce a  $4$% increase of $\eta$, while a $2$% increase of $l$ will induce a  $2$% decrease of $\eta$. If you have multiple changes, you just add them up.

In general, we do not know the sign of errors (we are given accuracies). In that case, you add up all the absolute values. Your case would then lead to   $$\frac{\Delta \eta }{\eta }=\frac{\text{$\Delta $l}}{l}+\frac{4 \text{$\Delta $r}}{r}+\frac{\text{$\Delta
   $v}}{v}$$

Do you see the difference between both situations ?

Comment: Therefore I could use one of the two equations, being; $$\Delta \eta =-\frac{\text{$\Delta $l} k r^4}{l^2 v}-\frac{\text{$\Delta $v} k r^4}{l
   v^2}+\frac{4 \text{$\Delta $r} k r^3}{l v}$$ or  $$\frac{\Delta \eta }{\eta }=\frac{\text{$\Delta $l}}{l}+\frac{4 \text{$\Delta $r}}{r}+\frac{\text{$\Delta
   $v}}{v}$$

Comment: Sorry I am slightly confused I haven't seen/used this method before. I know that the Viscosity is 7%. However I am finding a Viscosity of 6%. From the following Calculations.. .$$\frac{\Delta \eta }{\eta }=\frac{\text{$\Delta $0.03}}{0.03}+\frac{4 \text{$\Delta $0.02}}{0.02}+\frac{\text{$\Delta
   $0.04}}{0.04}$$

Comment: @Andre. If we speak about errors, the relative error on viscosity is 0.03 + 4 0.02 + 0.04 = 0.15 (so 15%). If we speak about signed changes, the relative error on viscosity is 0.03 + 4 0.02 - 0.04 = 0.07 (so 7%).

Comment: Brilliant! Additionally I am also struggling with another problem which you may be able to assist one with?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660952/engineering-mathematics

Comment: @Andre. I do not see where is the problem; the comments are quite clear. Could you elaborate ? I shall be happy to help (if I can). Cheers.

Comment: Firstly, to show the equation for instantaneous power, I take it that the instantaneous voltage (v) has been simplified and shown. Therefore to let one prove the equation, do I have to simplify the instantaneous current (i) to prove the equation?

Comment: Replace $i$ and $v$ in $P$. You have the formula. Now use the relation for cosine of double angle as a function of sine of the angle and you are done. By the way, you could accept my answer if you wish.

Comment: Therefore, considering the double angled formula and compound angles;                                                                                                                                                            cos 2x = cos^2 x - sin^2x,  cos^2 x + sin^2x = 1,              Substitution of:-  cos^2x = 1 - sin^2x, cos2x = (1 - sin^2x) -  sin^2x, cos2x = (1 - 2*sin^2x), 2*sin^2x = 1 - cos2x, sin^2x = (1/2)*(1 - cos2x)

Comment: Would I be correct in saying this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

I do not know how they teached you the problem of errors; so forgive me if it does not match what you have been told.

The easiest way (at least to me) is to consider the logarithm of $\eta$ and to take the derivatives with respect to each properties, each derivative being weighted by its error (this is equivalent to a total differentiation).

I shall only give you the answer, assuming that the errors you give are in percents : your viscosity would be in error by $15$ percent.

I am sure that you can take from here and establish the proper formula, valid for any error on any of the terms.

**Added later**

I realize now that I did not see the sign assigned to errors (I am almost blind). What I assumed is that you were given relative errors (accuracies) for each quantity. If they are what you wrote, my answer is an overall error of $7$ percent for viscosity.

If you want me to elaborate more, just post. We could go into more details.

Comment: Thank you. Therefore if I assign the relative errors (accuracies) for each quantity; r= (1+2%)r or r= (0.98r) and repeat this for the other respective quantities, I can substitute all of the quantities  i.e.(0.98r) into the equation to calculate the viscosity?

Comment: Not at all ! I shall write a more detailed answer.