# Mathematical proof for engineering (applying compound / double angle formulas)

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, physics

> The instantaneous current $i$ and the instantaneous voltage $v$ in a pure resistance a.c. circuit is given by:
>
> $$i=i_{\text{max}} \sin \omega t$$ $$ \text{and} \space v= v_{\text{max}} \sin \omega t$$
>
> Since the power follows:
>
> $$P = iv =i^2 R$$
>
> Show that an equation for instantaneous power is;
>
> $$P=i_{\text{max}}^2 R[1-\cos 2(\omega t)]/2$$

I have been revising basic compound angles and I am struggling to understand the following question from the examples I have previously studied on such topic.

I cannot see how the compound angle formulae relates to this question (if I am correct in thinking that it is relevant for a question of this nature).

A first step, or point of direction/suggestion would be brilliant. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you're question is "how can I turn $(\sin(\omega t))^2$ into a double-angle-type form", then you should look at your double angle formulas.

Comment: Would that be be the first part in the process to consider the double angled formula for instantaneous current and voltage to prove the equation?

Comment: @Andre I don't think I know what your question is asking, because I don't know what process you could possibly have in mind.  As far as I can tell, the $I^2$ in your formula leads to a sin-squared term, and all you're trying to do now is simplify that term.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am in the process of completing a past mathematics paper as revision in preparation for an exam in two weeks from which I came across the question in subject. I have to show the equation for instantaneous power is as the above, where I know the voltage, current and power. I interpreted  it in the form of 'compound angles', which I am no longer sure is correct? So any possible solutions given would be amazing!!

Comment: If you know that $\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2 x$, which you had better, then you can rearrange this formula to "solve" for $\sin^2 x$ and use that to replace the $\sin^2 x$ in your equation above.

Comment: Thanks. So regarding sin, is it then a case of substitution to prove?

Comment: Yes, you are going to replace $\sin^2 x$ with something that it is equal to (which obviously won't change the overall value).

Comment: Therefore, considering the double angled formula and compound angles; cos 2x = cos^2 x - sin^2x, cos^2 x + sin^2x = 1, Substitution of:- cos^2x = 1 - sin^2x, cos2x = (1 - sin^2x) - sin^2x, cos2x = (1 - 2*sin^2x), 2*sin^2x = 1 - cos2x, sin^2x = (1/2)*(1 - cos2x)

Comment: would I be correct in saying this?